# How to make ajax call in react? Its working in html

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, reactjs, fetch-api

```
class login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: 23 };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    var component = this;
    fetch('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(json) {
        var data = json;
        console.log(data[0]);
        console.log(data[1].title);
        component.setState({ data: json });
      });
  }
  render() {
    var someData = this.state.data[1].title || '';
    return <div> <h1>elo{someData}</h1> </div>;
  }
}
export default login;
```

The code above works only with array format not json response can anyone help in json response api how to fetch

Comment: When adding in script tag in html it is fetching the data from response api , But can anyone help me how to load that script tag in react component

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. Use an array as the initial state for `data`, as it will be an array after the fetch.
2. Check for `this.state.data.length` inside `render` to see if the fetch was successful, otherwise render nothing (or a loading indicator).
3. `fetch` requires a protocol, such as `https`. Always be sure to add that in front of the URL.
4. Minor thing: Usually it's *best practice* to capitalize component names. AFAIK it's up to you though.

Try this:

```js
class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: [] };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    var component = this;
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(json) {
        var data = json;
        console.log(data[0]);
        console.log(data[1].title);
        component.setState({ data: json });
      });
  }
  render() {
    var { data } = this.state;
    var someData = data.length ? data[1].title : '';
    return <div> <h1>elo{someData}</h1> </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Login />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Fetch Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead of the jquery's old ajax. Also you don't use $(document).ready() when you are developing in react, put a click handler, or any other javascript event and then further make your ajax call there.

Comment: class login extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
data: 23
};
}

componentDidMount() {
var component = this;


fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
.then(function(response) {
return response.json()
}).then(function(json) {
var data = json;
console.log(data[0]);
console.log(data[1].title);
component.setState({
data: json
})
})

}


render() {
var someData = this.state.data[1].title || "";
return (
<div>
<h1>elo{someData}</h1>


</div>
);
}
}


export default login;

Comment: when loading in react component only the array format response api is working in the UI but not json format

Comment: example with json response api in react component would be helpfull.

Comment: Firstly I don't understand the code the you have just written above in  the comment, please comment in proper format, just edit your question and paste your code, select the whole code and press `ctrl+k`

Comment: Thanks now you can check @aditya